# Replace non-blank cells with 0

Tags: replace, scripting, google-sheets

I tried to find solutions online however couldn't find one specifically for my need: I want to create a script which replaces non-blank cells in given column with 0.

Is there a simple solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function blankTo0() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var rng = s.getRange("A:A");//change to column you want
  var data= rng.getValues()
 for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == "") {
      data[i][0] = 0;
    } else if (data[i][0] == "") {
      data[i][0] = data[i][0];
    }}
rng.setValues(data); // replace old data with new
}
```